# Window.closed = true while the window is opened [Twitter OAuth2 in popup window]

Tags: javascript, twitter, oauth-2.0, oauth, twitter-oauth

## Information

I'm trying to implement *OAuth with Twitter* in a popup window, *same implementation works for Google and Discord*, currently what I am doing is, in a function named `openOAuthWindow` **I am creating a new window popup** with OAuth URL, **then creating a `Promise`** and saving `resolve` and `reject` functions in `window` object. After that, **in the child window** when the service redirects to my `redirect_uri`, my page calls saved `resolve` or `reject` in parent window (by reference from `window.opener`) depending on OAuth result and closes OAuth window. **After child is closed** I'm clearing `resolve` and `reject` functions from parent window and the Promise is correspondingly resolved or rejected. **Also I've set an interval** with `setInterval` which checks if `oAuthWindow.closed === true` (which indicates if the window has been closed). In case of `oAuthWindow.closed === true` and the `Promise` is not fulfilled that indicates that user closed the OAuth window manually and an `OAuthError` is returned as the result of Promise.

---

## The problem

As I've mentioned earlier, everything is fine with Google and Discord, the problem is with Twitter. When the Twitter OAuth page is fully loaded `oAuthWindow.closed` returns `true` (while the window is still opened), and my logic fails (because of the error that I'm throwing indicating that user closed the OAuth window manually). Also when I go to DevTools in `oAuthWindow`, the `window.opener` property equals to `null`. So my reference to the parent window is also lost.

---

## The actual questions

1. Is there an alternative way to check if window is opened or closed?
   (I've tried to find some solution, but couldn't find one)
2. Are there any alternative solutions to implement OAuth in popup
   window? (Any offers are appreciated)
3. Also are there any security drawbacks to avoid using OAuth 2 in
   popup? (I've done research on this, I've done investigation on OAuth
   security, the only security problem I have found could have been the
   access to child window from website, but that link is not possible
   due to **same origin policy**)

---

```
public static async openOAuthWindow(url: string, windowFeatures: string = "width=500,height=600,popup=true"): Promise<CodeAndState> {
    if(!windowFeatures.includes("noopener")) {
        const oAuthWindow: Window = window.open(url, "_blank", windowFeatures)!;

        let fulfilled = false;

        const removePromiseCallbacksAndFullfill = () => {
            delete window.returnAuthCode;
            delete window.returnOAuthError;
            fulfilled = true;
        };

        let resultPromise: Promise<CodeAndState> = new Promise<CodeAndState>((resolve, reject) => {
            window.returnAuthCode = resolve;
            window.returnOAuthError = reject;
        }).then((codeAndState: CodeAndState) => {
            removePromiseCallbacksAndFullfill();
            return codeAndState;
        }).catch((error) => {
            removePromiseCallbacksAndFullfill();
            return Promise.reject(error);
        });

        let windowAliveInterval = setInterval(() => {
            if (oAuthWindow.closed) {
                clearInterval(windowAliveInterval);
                if(!fulfilled) {
                    const error = new OAuthError("User closed the window", ERROR_STATUSES.USER_CLOSED_OAUTH_WINDOW);
                    window.returnOAuthError!(error);
                }
            }
        }, 500);

        return resultPromise;
    }
    throw new Error("OAuth window sends code to the parent window, so it must be opened without 'noopener' feature");
}
```

## Thank you for your efforts, any answer/comment is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I recently had this problem as well, where opening the Google OAuth prompt in a popup window was incorrectly considered "closed".

One solution you can consider looking at is to use a [broadcast channel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API): When the parent window opens the oauth popup, also open a broadcast channel. After the OAuth login, redirect to a page that sends the parent page a message before the popup window closes itself.

If the parent window does not receive any messages on the broadcast channel then that indicates the login was closed before it succeeded.

Comment: Yeah, I checked some solutions on this problem and I know about Broadcast Channels, but their problem is the support, as they are supported in small amount of browsers and their versions, for example safari and edge have support of Broadcast Channels from 2021, which is not from the far past, and also there was a solution with postMessage, but it requires reference to a window, so that's not an option. Thank you for your answer.  Currently the logic is implemented with redirects, but I'd like to wait for more answers on this topic.